# Unable to show Toast from onItemClick()

Tags: android, json, android-toast

Some One Can Help Me Please Told Me How To Show Room Id In Toast Below Is The Code. Below Code Working But I am Not Able To Show RoomId in Toast.

```
JSONArray rooms = jsonObject.getJSONArray("rooms");
for (int i = 0; i < rooms.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject room = rooms.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println("List Room Query".toString());
    System.out.println(room.toString());
    String rname = room.optString("room");
    String rnameid = room.optString("roomid");
    String outPut2 = rnameid;
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ChatlistView);
    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(RoomListActivity.this, roomList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {"chatroom"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
            int itemPosition     = position;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position :"+itemPosition, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }); 
}
```

Below is Hash

```
List<Map<String,String>> roomList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
private HashMap<String, String>createRoom(String name,String number){
    HashMap<String, String> roomName = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
    roomName.put(name, number); 
    return roomName;
}
```

Please Please Help Me How to Show Room Id In TOast

Comment: is your onItemClick() getting called? just keep a debug point and check

Comment: You are getting the values from JSON but you are never creating `roomList` using method `createRoom`. I am sure your list is not showing anything. And you don't add listener inside for loop. It needs to be outside of for.

Comment: What are you doing actually each time calling `findViewById(R.id.ChatlistView);`, setting Adapter each time in loop ?

Comment: Simply too many bugs in this code.

Comment: Now you told me **is this Toast showing up ?**

Comment: @Rohit5k2 haha I am afraid how this code is working...

Comment: these code is perfectly work on me

Comment: Please Check These Code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766183/json-to-listview-with-setonitemclicklistener-in-android

Answer (score -3):

Replace

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Position :"+itemPosition, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();
```

with

```
Toast.makeText(RoomListActivity.this,
        "Position :"+itemPosition, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();
```

Comment: What difference does it make?

Comment: it worked or not?  i mean toast is displaying with position.?

Comment: this not make any difference.