# listview OnItemClick listner not working

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I got the error. error and code is below anyone can solve these error.

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ChatlistView);
ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RoomListActivity.this,  
         R.layout.room_row,
         R.id.room,
         items);
listView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        TextView textView = (TextView) view; 
        String message = "You clicked # " + position + ", which is string: " + textView.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(RoomListActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

room_row.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativelay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/room"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img_room"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img_room"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_room"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/img_room"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="16dp" />



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_room"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/chat" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat:

```
03-08 12:53:50.775: E/AndroidRuntime(716): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
03-08 12:53:50.775: E/AndroidRuntime(716): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView 
03-08 12:53:50.775: E/AndroidRuntime(716): at com.android.wap2mob.RoomListActivity$1$1.onItemClick(RoomListActivity.java:126) 
03-08 12:53:50.775: E/AndroidRuntime(716): at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292) 
03-08 12:53:50.775: E/AndroidRuntime(716): at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058) 
03-08 12:53:50.775: E/AndroidRuntime(716): at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514) 
03-08 12:53:50.775: E/AndroidRuntime(716): at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168) 
03-08 12:53:50.775: E/AndroidRuntime(716): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 
03-08 12:53:50.775: E/AndroidRuntime(716): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
03-08 12:53:50.775: E/AndroidRuntime(716): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
03-08 12:53:50.775: E/AndroidRuntime(716): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
03-08 12:53:50.775: E/AndroidRuntime(716): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
03-08 12:53:50.775: E/AndroidRuntime(716): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
03-08 12:53:50.775: E/AndroidRuntime(716): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
03-08 12:53:50.775: E/AndroidRuntime(716): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
03-08 12:53:50.775: E/AndroidRuntime(716): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView`

Comment: post your xml please

Comment: means i am not understand

Comment: post ur xml becoz ur view is of type RelativeLayout and u r casting it to TextView so its not possible in that way, post your xml will tell u properly wt to do...

Comment: @saeedkhan add `TextView textView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.room);`

Comment: TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.room);

Comment: Please read the LogCat when a crash occurs. And if you don't understand a certain term, like in this case it was "ClassCastException", Google it or search on StackOverflow. If nothing comes up and you have tried your best, then post a question and explain clearly what you have tried. Show your effort so people can help you quickly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to show Toast from onItemClick()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745776/unable-to-show-toast-from-onitemclick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 03-08 12:53:50.775: E/AndroidRuntime(716): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 03-08
>   12:53:50.775: E/AndroidRuntime(716): java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.TextView 03-08 12:53:50.775: E/AndroidRuntime(716):

A **ClassCastException** is an Exception that can occur in a Java program when you try to improperly convert a class from one type to another.

Problem in here

```
  TextView textView = (TextView) view;
```

Try this way

```
 TextView textView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.room); // You are missing findViewById(R.id.room);
```

Comment: Thanks Problem Solved Thanks For the Help

Comment: @saeedkhan Move ahead .

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

Remove This line

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view;
```

Replace This :

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(id_here);
```

Comment: Thanks Problem Solved Thanks For the Help

Answer (score 0):

Find the textView by View provided in OnItemClick like,

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view;
```

replace above code with below one

```
TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ur_textview_id);
```

Comment: Thanks Problem Solved Thanks For the Help

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

happening when you trying to assign `view` object to `TextView` in your code, just change it as below:

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(Your textview id);
                String message = "You clicked # " + position + ", which is string: " + textView.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(RoomListActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
         });
```